# Display different layout according to Facebook connection status in Android

Tags: android, facebook, layout, authentication

I'm building an Android application where I want users to connect by their facebook details.
According to my design, when the application starts first time, I want to display a layout with LOGIN facebook button. After the user will perform login for the first time, I dont want to display this layout/activity again - when the application would be relanched,

I want t display another (home) screen, and not the LOGIN one.

How should I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of whether the user is logged in or not. The easiest way to accomplish this is probably by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html),  though there are a lot of different ways to accomplish this.

Some *pseudocode* will probably best illustrate how to do this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!SharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn")){
        // 1. User is not logged in, show login layout
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //  2. Let user login to Facebook

        //  3. If login successful: 
        SharedPreferences.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", true);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        startHomeActivity();

        // 4. ..else, show error message.
    } else {
        // isLoggedIn was true, so user is logged in. Start HomeActivity
        startHomeActivity()
    }
}

public void startHomeActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: But this means that anyhow I have to display the layout of the LOGIN (because of setContentView) and then to change it? Also, why should I use SharedPreferences instead of isSessionValid - isnt it enough?

Comment: Updated the answer. You can of course use isSessionValid instead of a SharedPreference as long as it keeps track of whether the user is logged in or not.